# Dataloades TypeError: __getitem___() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

it's my first time approaching pytorch. I built a dataset class to load tensors by Dataloader, like this:

```
train_loader = DataLoader(dataset_train, batch_size=6, drop_last=True)
```

But at the following line:

```
for i,train_batch in enumerate(train_loader):
```

I receive this error:
TypeError: __ getitem__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Any help would be great. I'm stuck on it.
My concern is that it could depend on the libraries versions I'm using:
matplotlib              3.5.2
numpy                   1.23.0
opencv-python           4.6.0.66
torch                   1.12.0
torch-tb-profiler       0.4.0
torchaudio              0.12.0
torchvision             0.13.0

Thank you.

Comment: how did you define dataset_train?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you expected to enumerate your dataloader:

```
for i, train_batch in enumerate(dataloader):
    # train loop
```

Comment: yes, sorry, I'll correct the mistake in the question. Thank you.

Comment: Can you show your dataset implementation?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem lies in how you define your `__getitem__` function in your custom dataset class. Make sure your `__getitem__` function takes `idx` argument, like so:

```
def __getitem__(self, idx):
  # your code
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by going into detail in the PyTorch documentation.
I suggest to everyone with the same issue to go through the PyTorch classes in the GitHub code.
Here is the datasets documentation: https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/datasets.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).